# Audio on add to cart with raw javascript

Tags: javascript

What exactly is wrong with my selection?

```
<a href="#" class="button-4 w-button"></a>

<audio id="cart_add_sound" controls="" preload="auto" hidden="hidden"> <source src="img/cart_add.wav"
type="audio/wav"> </audio>
```

- creating a function
- targeting class  `button-4`
- attaching an even listener to mouse click
- and play the audio with an id of  `cart_add_sound`

```
//  Play Audio on Add to Cart
  function playAudio() {
    var play = document.querySelector('.button-4')
    play.addEventListener('click', function() {  
        document.getElementById('cart_add_sound').play();
    }, true); 
}
```

i know i could use inside html5 `onclick="audio.play()"` but i want to approach it this way for learning purpose.

Comment: Ensure that **playAudio** is being called after the elements are defined. Also, add some text to your anchor tag to have a link to click on. Rest seems fine.

Comment: yeh first i thought i forgot to call the function but no, i called it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize / execute this function, for example, after the DOM is ready:

```
// Play Audio on Add to Cart
function playAudio() {
    var play = document.querySelector('.button-4')
    play.addEventListener('click', function() {  
        document.getElementById('cart_add_sound').play();
    }, true); 
}

// DOM ready event
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    playAudio();
});
```

Have you run it somewhere?

Demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/BaKKdvW

Comment: i have `if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}`

Comment: So does your `ready` function run / contain `playAudio()`? In general your code looks okey.

Comment: ok so far it works only one element with the class of  `button-4` the others are being ignored and  `queryselectorAll ` ain't doing the job.

Comment: `playAudio() ` is inside  my  `function addToCartClicked(event)`

Comment: @grace1989 I guess you should be more specific, so we can help you. Do you have a several elements, which trigger the palying?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by using `getElementsByClassName`
and looping through all elements.

```
//  Play Audio on Add to Cart
  function playAudio() {
    var plays = document.getElementsByClassName('button-4')
    for (var i = 0; i < plays.length; i++) {
        var play = plays[i]
    play.addEventListener('click', function() {  
        document.getElementById('cart_add_sound').play();
        }, true); 
    }
}
```